# Using Tooltips with link_to (Ruby on Rails 3.2.3)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have been successful in creating a tooltip for text using code similar to:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="something">text on page</a>
```

However I would like to do a tooltip for a link defined in a menu using the link_to command.  I have included the statement I would like a tooltip to appear for:

```
<li><i class="icon-edit"></i>&nbsp;<%= link_to current_user.first_name+' '+current_user.last_name, edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
```

Here is the JS code in bootstrap.js.coffee:

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip()
$("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

I am a student still learning a lot about Rails, Twitter Bootstrap, CSS3, HTML5, etc.  I have done many web searches but have not found any examples of this that I understood.  Basically there is nothing that says directly that I can do a tooltip within a link_to statement that worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This way:

```
link_to 'Text', '/link', title: 'some title', rel: 'tooltip'
```

**update:**

It's ruby 1.9 syntax. For 1.8 it would be

```
link_to 'Text', '/link', :title => 'some title', :rel => 'tooltip'
```

Comment: ok32, thanks so much for your help.  That worked.  I needed to place the tooltip at the bottom.  I was glad to find out how to code the options through another Stack Overflow post:)