# Bootstrap tooltips in eex templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a bootstrap tooltip. A test link works OK here:

```
<a data-tooltip="I am tooltip text" data-placement="left">Clickame</a>
```

I have an eex link:

```
 <span><%= link "  ", to: post_path(@conn, :show, post), class: "btn btn-default btn-md btn-read-post unicode-lg" %></span>
```

I tried to wrap anchor tags around the link:

```
    <a data-tooltip="edit" data-placement="left"><span><%= link "    ", to: post_path(@conn, :show, post), class: "btn btn-default btn-md btn-read-post unicode-lg" %></span></a>
```

... didn't work.

There are some ideas in this Ruby on Rails tooltip question:

[Using Tooltips with link_to (Ruby on Rails 3.2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626924/using-tooltips-with-link-to-ruby-on-rails-3-2-3)

rel: "data-tooltip" does not raise an error:

```
<span><%= link "  ", to: post_path(@conn, :show, post), class: "btn btn-default btn-md btn-read-post unicode-lg", rel: "data-tooltip" %></span>
```

but how do I add the data-placement="left" class?

Full tooltip here:

https://codepen.io/peiche/pen/JaftA

```
a[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

a[data-tooltip]::before,
a[data-tooltip]::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.85;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the `<a>` with `data-tooltip` and `data-placement` attributes by passing the attribute and their values as a keyword list to `Phoenix.HTML.Link.link/2`:

```
<%= link("Clickame", to: "/", "data-tooltip": "I am tooltip text", "data-placement": "left") %>
```

This produces the following HTML, which should work with your tooltip:

```
<a data-placement="left" data-tooltip="I am tooltip text" href="/">Clickame</a>
```

Comment: Thanks again Dogbert. Lightning fast as usual. Will try that right now + report back.

Answer (score 1):

The correct tooltip syntax for the link, including classes, would be:

```
<%= link("   ", to: post_path(@conn, :show, post), "data-tooltip": "I am tooltip text", "data-placement": "left", class: "btn btn-default btn-md btn-read-post unicode-lg") %>
```

original:

```
<span><%= link "  ", to: post_path(@conn, :show, post), class: "btn btn-default btn-md btn-read-post unicode-lg" %></span>
```